# check user rights to do something

Tags: php, laravel-4

i am creating user permissions on laravel. In my DB i have table with id/user_id/model/write/read/delete

last three permission is enum type: on and off.

in my User model im wrote method to set:

```
protected $models   = ['dashboard', 'preferences'];  

public function setPermissions($input=false)             
    {
        foreach($this->models as $model) {
            $read   = (isset($input[$model]['read']) ? 'on' : 'off');
            $write  = (isset($input[$model]['write']) ? 'on' : 'off');
            $delete = (isset($input[$model]['delete']) ? 'on' : 'off');

            $perms          = Permissions::firstOrNew([
                'user_id'   => $this->id,
                'model'     => $model,
            ]);

            $perms->read    = $read;
            $perms->write   = $write;
            $perms->delete  = $delete;
            $perms->save();
        }
    }
```

in permission model im write:

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Permissions extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $table    = 'user_permissions';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'model', 'read', 'write', 'delete'];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id','id');
    }

}
```

ok, i have the method how to set permission from setting form. Now i need to check the right if the user have permission write or read, delete and do somehting like this:

```
if (Auth::user->hasRights('write', 'delete'))
          //do something
```

Please help me how to select from DB permissions and check user right with hasRight method.

i think that need to check if user permissions from DB is in array. How this should look?

and maybe can you tiny code of my setPermission method? thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
// in User model
public function hasRights(...$accessLevels)
{
    return ! $this->permissions()->filter(function (Permissions $p) use ($accessLevels) {
        foreach ($accessLevels as $access) {
            if ( ! $p->{$access}) return false;
        }
        return true;
    })->isEmpty();
}
```